# Difference between message map and overriding windowproc

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I whould like to ask, when i'm programming in MFC, what is the difference between message map, and overriding windowproc? 
In which cases I have to override windowproc?

For example, when do I have to use the message ON_WM_CHAR, and when do i have to override windowproc and catch the case of WM_CHAR?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For most practical purposes you'd *always* use ON_WM_CHAR rather than overriding its window proc.

You'd override its window proc primarily when you need to change the fundamental behavior of the message loop -- but that's quite rare (the only instances I can think of right off are some things like animated games, that need to execute code on a regular basis, so you modify the main loop to include (a call to) some screen-update code.

Comment: Agree. Another common reason to override is to modify the default routing of a message (although that can often be accomplished in `PreTranslateMessage`).